# What kind of feeds should the chat have?

Tags: discussion, chat

For a long time, the U&L [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26/unix-and-linux) has [feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26/unix-and-linux?tab=feeds) of incoming questions from the main site and the meta site.

There are two possible methods to let the feeds into the room:

- message-style: a link to each post is posted as a message; “one-boxing” provides a question preview
- ticker-style: an overlay appears at the top of the chatroom window

The feeds were recently switched from message-style to ticker-style.

Should the feeds go back to message style? remain in ticker style? go away altogether?

---

Given that nobody is defending the ticker feeds, can they be removed? Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate the ticker style:

- It's a box that you need to click to dismiss (or if you don't dismiss it, it keeps growing up to a point, and keeps moving).
- It's useless as a conversation started, because you can't “reply” to a post.
- It's useless as a notification of new posts, now that you can get it faster through the live updates of the home page. (The same goes for the message style, but it at least has other uses.)
- It makes the room seem dead: whole days can go by without any activity. At about 40/day, the messages aren't so frequent as to interrupt conversation, but do keep the room a bit busy.
- If you don't like message feeds, you can ignore the feeds user. If you don't like the ticker, tough.

Fortunately, [you can turn off the ticker in Firefox and Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115224/can-i-silence-ticker-feeds-in-a-chat-room/170667#170667). It would be friendlier to new users not to have the damn thing at all, but at least we can turn it off on an individual basis.

Comment: The main problem with the message style is #4, which you've somehow spun into a positive -- the constant feeds messages hide posts from actual users. I used to miss real messages all the time; I'd be scrolling through the backlog and see a message from days ago that I hadn't realized ever happened. Feeds posts look like normal posts, so if they're 95% of the posts in the room people will stop checking. #1 is true, but the fixed size box doesn't seem like a problem. #2 is totally unimportant; just post a link to the question. #3 isn't specific to the ticker. #5 is true, but should be fixable

Comment: @MichaelMrozek [fix it and I'll come back to the room](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115224/can-i-silence-ticker-feeds-in-a-chat-room)